# Springboot controller login

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

У меня написан обычный метод для контроллера:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody User u)throws ServletException {
    String jwtToken = "";
    String email = u.getEmail();
    String password = u.getPassword();
    //checks

    jwtToken = Jwts.builder().setSubject(email).claim("roles", "user").setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secretkey").compact();

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(jwtToken, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

И он правильно работает, когда приходят данные в следующем формате:

```
{"email": "example@gmail.com", "password": "123456"}
```

Меня интересует вопрос, что нужно сделать, чтобы принять правильно следующий запрос:

```
{"credentials": {"email": "example@gmail.com", "password": "123456"}}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо создать сущность, у которой будет поле типа User, имя поля должно быть credentials.

```
class Credentials{
     User credentials;
}
```

И тогда ваш метод должен принимать Credentials

```
public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody Credentials u)throws ServletException
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!